# null at my answer

Tags: scala

I am executing the following code:

```
def takeN(s : String, n : Int): String = {
    var j = 1
    var o = s.split("")
    if(n != 0){
      var arr = new Array[Char](n)
    }
    while(j <= n){
      arr(j) = o(j)
      j += 1
    }
    val ml = List.fromArray(arr)
    var newS = ml.mkString("")
    newS
  }
```

When I test this code with this takeN("abcd",2), the answer that I am getting is this:

```
nullab
```

When I run this code at: http://www.simplyscala.com/ everything works but when I try it at my home pc I get errors so I changed it to :

```
     def takeN(s : String, n : Int): String = {
    var j = 1
    var o = s.split("")
    var arr = new Array[Char](n)
    while(j <= n){
      arr(j) = o(j)
      j += 1
    }
    val ml = List.fromArray(arr)
    var newS = ml.mkString("")
    newS
  }
```

then I get this error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String
 required: Char
             arr(j) = o(j)
```

I am not sure how to fix this. why scala is so hard??

Comment: The scope of `arr` is limited to the block, following the `if`. Outside, there is no arr defined, except you're trying this in the REPL, and have an outer arr. Else, this code doesn't compile.

Comment: Why do you name those variables o, j, arr and m1? What does it mean? Who should follow your intention?

Comment: I was just trying to get it done and see how it works, didnt really think to give them good names. they dont mean anything o is an array representation of string S. j is to be used within the while loop, arr is a array has the answer in it. and I used ml to be able to make the array into a string

Comment: Better names would have been, in, out, arr, list while j is fine for an index, but between all those 1 letter names, it is just another one. newS or ml is worse. You don't need a name for the returned result, but `result` can be fine, if you need it before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a recursive answer without all that vals and vars. Most code is to guard agains invalid input:

```
def takeN (s : String, n : Int): String = {
  if (n > s.length) sys.error ("n > s.length: " + n  + " > " + (s.length))
  else if (n < 0) sys.error ("n < 0 : " + n)
  else if (n == 0) ""
  else if (n == s.length) s 
  else s(0) + takeN (s.substring (1), n-1) }
```

A shorter solution (but without guard) is:

```
def takeN (s : String, n: Int): String =
   (0 to n-1).map (s(_)).mkString
```

usage:

```
takeN ("foolish", 5)
res16: String = fooli
```

But let's try an solution closer to your approach:

```
  def takeN (s: String, n: Int): String = {
    var j = 0
    var arr = new Array[Char](n)
    while (j < n) {
      arr (j) = s(j)
      j += 1
    }
    val ml = List.fromArray (arr)
    var newS = ml.mkString("")
    newS
  }
```

String indexes start (as in Java) with 0, and so we go to j < n, not j <= n and from 0, not 1. We don't need 'o' (with dubious split (""), since we can use s(j) instead too.

Next step, get rid of the intermediate List:

```
  def takeN (s: String, n: Int): String = {
    var j = 0
    var arr = new Array[Char](n)
    while (j < n) {
      arr (j) = s(j)
      j += 1
    }
    arr.mkString 
  }
```

We simplified the return. Now let's use a for-loop, instead of the while:

```
  def takeN (s: String, n: Int): String = {
    val arr = for (j <- (0 to n-1)) yield s(j)
    arr.mkString 
  }
```

or just

```
  def takeN (s: String, n: Int): String =
    (for (j <- (0 to n-1)) yield s(j)).mkString
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is not very idiomatic Scala, but the language has this functionality built in:

```
scala> "abcd".take(2)
res0: String = ab
```

If you really want a method with that signature, you could just do:

```
def takeN(s: String, n: Int) = 
  s.take(n)
```

Comment: yeah I am learning scala and I have to try to make the method takeN

Comment: @Saeed What exactly are you trying to do?  Just have a method called `takeN` with those parameters?  Use a specific aspect of Scala?

Comment: I believe I cant do this I have to write the entire method by my self.

Comment: Also next week I have the exam of scala trying to learn it first hand!

Comment: @Saeed, do you know exactly what language features you are allowed to use and which you are not?  I mean, there are lots of ways to do this that are much easier and more idiomatic than using arrays and while loops.

Comment: I have been using programming with scala BOOK and honestly this book is not so clear!!  I get confused.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that arrays start at index 0. Here `null` is just the initial value of the array elements.

A simpler alternative is to use the standard Scala API:

```
scala> "abcd".take(2)
res0: String = ab
```

Comment: I have to write the entire method on my own, try to learn scala!

Comment: Java,c, haskell, html, Css, Javascript and some more, i am better in Java and html css javascript

Comment: So, try to implement it in Java first. All objects here (String and Array) are exactly the same as the Java ones...